# display waiting dialog box while downloading the file in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am generating excel file from sql database, sql datatable contain 50k data so that file took long time to download. so i want to display one waiting dialog box to user while downloading that file. Any suggestion?

Comment: i tried to use settimeout for dialog but i have 2 diff file and both took diff time so i want to make it dynamically. when file download that dialog must be disappear.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the way I did it using jquery. this will show a loading image during a long process.

Add a gif(loading image) in your _Layout.cshtml. Put this inside the body.

```
<div id="loaderblock"></div>
    <div id="loadercontainer">
        <img src="~/Images/sampleloadingimage.gif" />
    </div>
```

add this to your Site.css

```
#loadercontainer { display:none;position: fixed;margin-top: 20%; margin-left: 45%;  z-index: 999999;}

#loaderblock {background: #000; opacity:0.6;  position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top:0; left:0; display:none;}
```

add this javascript in your view.

```
function generateexcel() {
 $('#loaderblock').fadeIn();
 $('#loadercontainer').fadeIn();

 $("#idofyourform").submit(); //submit your form

}
```

and change your submit button to something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Generate Excel" onclick="generateexcel();" />
```

this sample will show you how it works: [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rcadaoas/ws3my/)

Answer (score 0):

that is not my issuse.i want that loading image display only while the file is downloading.when file is successfully download and save dialog appear on browser at that time loading image should disappear automatically.